# Erro ao inserir dados de um ficheiro excel em sql

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-excel

Eu estou com um problema quando insiro dados do ficheiro excel para a base de dados pois num campo que eu estou a inserir diz que não é do tipo `time` e não deixa inserir , mas no ficheiro excel o texto que está la escrito é só horas ou seja do tipo `time`.
Aqui está uma print do campo do excel que eu estou a falar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a configuração da tabela de excel:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código que eu uso para escrever os dados na tabela de sql:

```
string ConecçãoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConecçaoDB"].ConnectionString;
            string Table = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["table"];

            string ssqltable = Table;

            string ssqlconnectionstring = ConecçãoDB;
            string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;


            var connectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filename+";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            // var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=0;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + comboBox1.Text + "$]";
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);

            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(sql);
            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oledbconn);
            oledbconn.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring))
                {
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox2.Text, "TransDate");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox3.Text, "TransTime");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox4.Text, "CardNo");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox5.Text, "VoucherNo");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox6.Text, "Quantity");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox7.Text, "TransactionValue");

                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }
            }
            oledbconn.Close();
            button2.Enabled = true;
            oledbconn.Close();
```

Este é o erro que me dá :

> InvalidCastException: Conversão inválida de 'System.DateTime' em
>   'System.TimeSpan'.

Comment: Me diga como está o conteúdo de: comboBox2 e comboBox3

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro tem os nomes dos campos de excel

Comment: O problema é o seguinte, a coluna TIME no sql, se não me engano, é mesmo um timespan (em milissegundos). O que eu faria é criar uma coluna varchar, e armazenar o valor. Ou uma coluna int, que armazenasse o valor da hora sem a formatação.

Comment: @PedroAzevedo coloca o stacktrace do erro por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a coluna do Excel contém `Date`, ou `Time`, ou `DateTime`, independente do formato, o ACE.OLEDB sempre vai mapeá-la para um tipo `DateTime`.

Então, o erro de conversão está ocorrendo porque a coluna `TransTime` no SQL Server é do tipo `Time` e a do Excel é `DateTime`.

Para corrigir o problema, você pode tentar uma dessas alternativas:

**Opção 1**: alterar a coluna `TransTime` do SQL Server para `DateTime`

**Opção 2**: tentar mudar a query para:

```
        SELECT cstr(TransDate) as TransDate, TransTime, ...  FROM [Plan1$]
```

**Obs**: não tive como testar esta segunda opção porque não tenho SQL Server instalado na minha máquina mas acredito que vá funcionar. A função `cstr(TransDate)` vai fazer um `Cast` da hora para `string` e o SQL Server acostuma fazer cast automático de `string` para `time`.

Comment: @Pedro, por curiosidade, qual foi a opção que você utilizou?